# Use the same counter for definitions and theorems

Tags: numbering, theorems

```
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section] 
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[section] 

\begin{defn}
--some text
\end{defn}

\begin{thm}
--some text
\end{thm}
```

when using the above commands i get as output the following code:

Definition 1.1
Theorem 1.1

But i want as output the following values:
Definition 1.1
Theorem **1.2**

Every time theorem and definition is used only the decimal values should be incremented. How can i do this?

Answer (score 6):

Use the optional argument to say `defn`should be numbered like `thm`

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section] 
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}

\begin{document}

\section{zzz}

\begin{defn}
--some text
\end{defn}

\begin{thm}
--some text
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this that doesn't require the the "defn" - theorem to be defined in terms of "thm" ? Say, I have 10 different custom theorem types that I all want to follow the same section-counter. Must they all be defined in terms of "thm" or in terms of one another ?

Comment: @AfterMath don't ask questions as comments on old posts, but your request seems contradictory  `\newtheorem{defn}[thm]` just says to use the `thm` counter for `defn`.  If you want multiple types to use the same counter you have to specify that counter.

Comment: I see. I thought '\newcounter{somecounter}[section]' together with '\newtheorem{thm}[somecounter]{Theorem}' and '\newtheorem{defn}[somecounter]{Definition}' could do the trick, but this does not show the theorem number together with the section number, and the section number does not appear when referring to the theorem.